# Jenkins - masking credentials created when pipeline runs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

For the declarative pipeline, I used to store standard passwords and usernames within the Jenkins instance. And used something like this within the pipeline:

```
CredentialVar = credentials('Credential_Name')
```

But now I have an api that will only accept refresh tokens which will expire. Basically, I think the solution is to request a new token each time with an API call when the pipeline is built, but I don't know how to mask that new response token each time.

Comment: So you have credentials stored in credential manager.  You want to make an API call to refresh a token. How does this related to masking credentials?  Your question is unclear.  Are you saying you want to mask the response ( which contains a token ) from an API call?  Why don't you just not print it to the build log

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness, Yes I want to mask the response from the API call. I'm not sure why I would want to print the response (which contains the token) to the build log, as you suggest. @ChrisMaggiulli

Comment: So my answer would probably be to not print the token to the build log and therefore you don't need to mask it.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No you're good, I'm probably the one misunderstanding. Wouldn't I have to mask it if I am using that response token in another API call? Performing that call with an unmasked token, I imagine, would prompt a jenkins warning. @ChrisMaggiulli

Comment: Jenkins won't warn you because it doesn't know that the data is sensitive.  I personally would just configure any subsequent call to not print to the build log, and additionally if you're making subsequent calls with the httpRequest step ( which I highly suggest ) it will automatically mask an Authorization header regardless

Comment: ok, I haven't tried it yet but thank you @ChrisMaggiulli